# How do I format a date string without changing the culture?

Tags: javascript

I am getting string data from a Google Calendar feed. The date is already set, by parameter, with the desired timezone.

```
2014-05-24T07:00:00.000-04:00
```

I know there are wonderful libraries like moment.js and date.js this will help format my date, but they also work with a Date object, which throws my date into a client's culture. At that point I am then juggling offsets. Would rather avoid that.

Other than a lot of conditional string manipulation, is there a simple way to do this, or I am oversimplifying (again)?

Example:

**2014-05-24T07:00:00.000-04:00** to **May, 24, 2014 - 7:00 AM**

Comment: I would use a regex. I think that's rather elegant

Comment: So all you want to do is reformat the date part from 2014-05-24 to May, 24, 2014 and ignore the time?

Comment: No, my mistake, I do NOT want to ignore the time.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the question clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following short code will parse your date, using the values present, without offsetting by the timezone:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var res = /(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)T(\d+)\:(\d+)/
        .exec('2014-05-24T07:00:00.000-04:00');
var am = (res[4] < 12);
var date = months[res[2]-1] + ', ' + res[3] + ', ' + res[1];
var time = am ? (parseInt(res[4]) + ':' + res[5] + 'AM') :
        (res[4] - 12 + ':' + res[5] + 'PM');
var formatted = date + ' - ' + time;
console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: +1, but there is no need for parseInt, array indexes are just Object properties so the names are strings. You can just do `var res = string.match(/\d+/g)` to get the parts and use bits 1, 2 and 0. :-)

Comment: @RobG You are correct that the indices are properties, but when using a string as a property name, it still has to be an exact match. Try this: `[1, 2, 3, 4]['01']`. It doesn't work

Comment: Month returned is June, no May.

Comment: @acbabis—yes, but you should be doing `months[--res[2]]`. If using *parseInt* and expecting leading zeros, you should be using a radix: `parseInt(res[2],10)`.

Comment: Cool, but you either need to decrement the month number or add an elision to the start of the months array - in your array, `months[5]` is June, not May. Decrementing the month number using `--` will do the conversion to number and decrement in one step. :-)

Comment: I used this in my solution. The idea of letting the Google Calendar API set the timezone and then not re-cast the date simply in order to get formatting is a powerful one, and one that this solution way key for.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this string into a Date object like below,

```
new Date("2014-05-24T07:00:00.000-04:00")
```

Then you can easily convert this date object into your desired format by using any of the jQuery libraries such as **jquery.globalize.js** ...

Comment: Despite ES5, parsing of date strings by the Date constructor is still largely implementation dependent. Much better to split the string into its parts and parse it manually. Also, converting it to a date object isn't what the OP wants to do as the date should be preserved and not be affected by different time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var d = new Date('2014-05-24T07:00:00.000-04:00');

var calendar = {
    months: {
        full: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        short: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    days: {
        full: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
        short: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    }
};

console.log(calendar.months.short[d.getMonth()]+', '+d.getDate()+', '+d.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to reformat the string is:

```
function reformatDateString(s) {
  s = s.match(/\d+/g);
  var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                'August','September','October','November','December'];
  var ampm = s[3]<12? 'AM':'PM';
  return months[--s[1]] + ', ' + +s[2] + ', ' + s[0] + ' - ' +
               (s[3]%12 || 12) + ':' + s[4] + ' ' + ampm;
}

console.log(reformatDateString('2014-05-24T07:00:00.000-04:00')); // May, 24, 2014 - 7:00 AM
console.log(reformatDateString('2014-05-24T17:00:00.000-04:00')); // May, 24, 2014 - 5:00 PM
console.log(reformatDateString('2014-05-04T00:20:00.000-04:00')); // May, 4, 2014 - 12:20 AM
```

Which also assumes that you don't want leading zeros on single digit numbers except for the minutes, as a time like `12:5 PM` isn't as readable (to me) as `12:05 PM`.

Also you may need to modify the months array, it's not clear in the OP whether you want full month names or abbreviations (Jan, Feb, etc.).